# Using Selenium IE driver in C# to quickly post a large amount of text (10,000 lines)

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver

So I'm currently writing this script that will automate a simple, monotonous task using the Selenium Internet Explorer driver in C#.

Everything works great, but it is a tad bit slow at one point in the script and I'm wondering if there is a quicker way available to do what I want.

The point in question is when I have to fill out a textbox with a lot of information. This textbox will be filled sometimes up to 10,000 lines where each line never exceeds 20 characters.

However, the following approach is very slow...

```
// process sample file using LINQ query
var items = File.ReadAllLines(sampleFile).Select(a => a.Split(',').First());

// Process the items to be what we want to add to the textbox
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var item in items)
{
     stringBuilder.Append(item + Environment.NewLine);
}

inputTextBox.SendKeys(stringBuilder.ToString());
```

Is there any to just set the value of the textbox to what I want? Or is this a bottleneck?

Thank you for your time and patience!

Comment: How big are we talking? 200,000+ lines? 100 lines? 3000 *characters*? Would be useful if you could quantify "large". What browser is this in? Does using a different one help?

Comment: This is in IE. We're talking between 1,000 and 10,000 lines. The lengths of the lines are under 20 characters each.

Comment: You could use javascript and IJavaScriptExecutor to set the field.  SendKeys, as I understand it, sends one char at a time.  Using javascript to set the value of the textarea should be much faster.

Comment: From what I've seen thus far it seems to be the most elegant solution. I'm currently checking it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as suggested by Richard - I ended up using `IJavaScriptExecutor`.

The exact solution was to replace the call to `SendKeys` in the following line of code:

```
inputTextBox.SendKeys(stringBuilder.ToString());
```

With this line of code:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)ieDriver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].value = arguments[1]",
                                          inputTextBox, stringBuilder.ToString());
```

Casting my `InternetExplorerDriver` object to the `IJavaScriptExecutor` interface in order to reach the explicitly implemented interface member `ExecuteScript` and then making the call to that member with the arguments above did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid using SendKeys, you could use IJavaScriptExecutor to set the value directly.  Something along these lines:

```
string javascript = "document.getElementById("bla").value = stringBuilder";
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver;
js.ExecuteScript(javascript);
```