# How to create one method to perform a send each character in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

Because of IE, whenever I perform a sendkeys, I will have to do a foreach loop to enter in each character of an element like so:

```
    public void CompleteOtherContactDetails()
    {


        var firstName = _driver.FindElement(PaymentDetailsResponsiveElements.OtherFirstNameField);
        var lastName = _driver.FindElement(PaymentDetailsResponsiveElements.OtherLastNameField);
        var firstNameText = _characterGenerator.RandomStringGenerator(8);
        var lasstNameText = _characterGenerator.RandomStringGenerator(8);

        foreach (char c in firstNameText)
            firstName.SendKeys(c.ToString());

        foreach (char c in lasstNameText)
            lastName.SendKeys(c.ToString());

    }
```

...

```
 public void FillEmailAddressField(string emailAddress)
    {
        var email = _driver.FindElement(PaymentDetailsResponsiveElements.EmailAddressField);
        var emailText = emailAddress;

        foreach (char c in emailText)
        {
            email.SendKeys(c.ToString());
        }
    }
```

...

```
    public void FillConfirmEmailAddressField(string emailAddress)
    {
        var confirmEmail = _driver.FindElement(PaymentDetailsResponsiveElements.ConfirmEmailAddressField);
        var emailText = emailAddress;

        foreach (char c in emailText)
        {
            confirmEmail.SendKeys(c.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I am still learning c# but I wanted to ask, is there a way and can you show me if a single method can be instead written so I don't have to keep writing the foreach loop to enter text, instead I can call on the method instead?

Thanks

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18987095/using-selenium-ie-driver-in-c-sharp-to-quickly-post-a-large-amount-of-text-10-0) shows how to do it using the ExecuteScript method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the wider context here but to give you a simple method to use, try something like this:

```
public void FillField(string fieldValue, WhateverTypeYourFieldHas field)
{
    var element=_driver.FindElement(field);
    foreach(char c in fieldValue)
    {
        element.SendKeys(c.ToString());
    }
}
```

You could use it like this

```
public void FillEmailAddressField(string emailAddress)
{
    FillField(emailAddress, PaymentDetailsResponsiveElements.EmailAddressField);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the following code:

```
public void FillEmailAddressField(string emailAddress)
    {
        var email = _driver.FindElement(PaymentDetailsResponsiveElements.EmailAddressField);
        var emailText = emailAddress;

        foreach (char c in emailText)
        {
            email.SendKeys(c.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Like:

```
public void FillEmailAddressField(string emailAddress)
    {
        var email = _driver.FindElement(PaymentDetailsResponsiveElements.EmailAddressField);
        email.SendKeys(emailAddress);
    }
```

I think you are using selenium. Selenium function SendKeys can send full string instead of characters.

Comment: The problem is IE, in Ie it actually misses out text when using send keys the normal way. So If I type in ABCDEFG, in Chrome it works but IE it may type ABDEG

Comment: In works in Chrome therefore, the code is fine. There might be a problem in webdriver. Which version of WebDriver and WebDriver.Support u r using?

Comment: Webdriver 3.6.0 and  Support 3.6.0

Comment: What is the Internet Explorer version?

Comment: IE11 and the IEWebdriver is also 3.6

Comment: SendKeys works fine in my machine. I was using 64 bit IEWebdriver, which was very slow. but 32 bit works fine. Can you check if it is 32 bit?

Comment: I have a 32 bit.Can you do me a favour, can you change your keyboard settings to USA and see if this causes an issue. What is happening in my work computer it is default set to USA but I cannot chnge it because if I go into langiuages, my computer crashes. I need to raise that with my technical support team but can you see if there is an issue on US language keyboard on yours please and let me know

Comment: Hi, I change my Keyboard to US, still sendkeys works. I will suggest  to use a different IEWebdriver. Try to use version 3.0.0.0